# Add overlay to video and save it on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, video, avfoundation

I need to record a video and add a simple `UIView` overlay to it, but I also need to save it with that overlay. My problem is only with saving the video with the overlay. Do I need to add that to the video after I finished recording? And if so, how? It should work the same way as it is in the "InstaWeather" app.
Thanks in advance.